# Trying to replace a value if it matches a specific criteria - Python For Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, append

I want to iterate over 2 different lists.  The first list I want to go through each item and check to see if it has a 90% or greater match with each item in the second list.  If it does, I want it to replace it with the queried value, if it doesn't I want it to put "Other".

I want this to go through every iteration, and if the iteration ever has a 90% match, I want it to replace "Other" with the queried value.

Below is my current code:

```
query = ['1000','ranch','blue cheese','honey dijon']
col = ['bar','foo','man','blue cheese','soup','honey dijon']

for query in query:
    newtext = []
    for x in col:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, x, query, autojunk=True).ratio() > .9:
            newtext.append(query)
        else:
            if newtext == 'Other':
                newtext.replace(query)
            else:
                newtext.append('Other')
print(newtext)
```

The Output of the above is :

```
['Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'honey dijon']
```

I want it to be:

```
['Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'blue cheese', 'Other', 'honey dijon']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: were you able to get the output with the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some improvements in your code; I have change your code little bit and see the difference:

```
import difflib

query = ['1000','ranch','blue cheese','honey dijon']
col = ['bar','foo','man','blue cheese','soup','honey dijon']

newtext = []
for x in col:
    for y in query:  
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y, autojunk=True).ratio() > .9:
            newtext.append(y)
            break
    else:
        newtext.append('Other')
print(newtext)

#output
['Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'blue cheese', 'Other', 'honey dijon']
```

`newtext` list is above both the for loops;

I have use a `break` statement once it finds the matching value;

I have used `for-else` combination once search is exhausted.